# How can I get figure to refresh after changing an object's axes in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, axes

Please refer to the example below. Two subplots are added, and to each a Line2D plot is inserted. I then change the Line2D's axes in the second subplot to be the first subplot. Judging by the `get_geometry` output this is successful. However in the actual figure the two Line2D plots are still in their original subplots.

What am I missing here? How can I refresh the figure to reflect the axes change?

Obviously this is a fairly moronic example, the real application is more of a dynamic nature.

Script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()  
ax_1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax_1.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,2])
ax_2.plot([0,1,2],[2,1,0])

print 'before'
for line in ax_1.get_lines():
    print line.get_ydata()
    print line.get_axes().get_geometry()
    print id(line.get_axes())

for line in ax_2.get_lines():
    print line.get_ydata()
    print line.get_axes().get_geometry()
    print id(line.get_axes())

f = ax_2.get_lines()[0]
f.set_axes(ax_1)

print 'after'
for line in ax_1.get_lines():
    print line.get_ydata()
    print line.get_axes().get_geometry()
    print id(line.get_axes())

for line in ax_2.get_lines():
    print line.get_ydata()
    print line.get_axes().get_geometry()
    print id(line.get_axes())

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
before
[0 1 2]
(2, 1, 1)
4330504912
[2 1 0]
(2, 1, 2)
4336262288
after
[0 1 2]
(2, 1, 1)
4330504912
[2 1 0]
(2, 1, 1)
4330504912
```

Figure output:
[image: Figure]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  maybe there is a better method than drawing a line in one graph and "moving it" to another one?

Comment: Like I said in the original post, the example above is silly. The real application is a gui charting application that is a little bit involved than the example. Regardless of the application though, I don't see the point of having a `set_axes` function if it doesn't actually change anything.

Comment: I think it's `axes.add_line()` that you want, but I can't seem to get it to work yet. So far I've created a new line, used `update_from()` to copy `f` into this new line, and then I've added it to the other axes. This still doesn't work, but it might for your application. I don't think it works for me because I don't think the splines used to make the line are updated for the new axes, but I'm looking into this....

Comment: Currently I am copying all the data (xydata) and metadata (color, linewidth etc) from the line in the old axes. I then delete the line in the old axes, and I plot the new one in the new axes (with the line's extracted data and metadata). I have always done it like this. Then just the other day I saw `set_axes` in the docs, but I can't get it to work (as I assume it is meant to work). Perhaps I have misunderstood the axes mechanics in matplotlib, but as far as I can see I think it's counterintuitive behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later on I posted the same question [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/), and [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/430) was the response.

**TL,DR**
It's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one problem is that your first axes (`ax_1`) do not have the line that you want to add (`f`) in their list of lines (`ax_1.lines`).

You can "copy" the line from the second plot to the first one with

```
f = ax_2.lines.pop()  # Removes the line from the second plot
ax_1.plot(*f.get_data())  # Draws a new line in the first plot, but with the coordinates of the second line
```

(with this method, there is obviously no need to do `f.set_axes(ax_1)`).  Other arguments to `plot()` could be used in order to also copy the color, etc., I guess.

Comment: Well, that's just another symptom of the same problem, that is, that the axes ax_2's line, f, hasn't been changed properly. After the axes change both Line2D objects point to the same axes object.

Comment: @c00kiemonster: Could you expand on that?  I would not expect `f` to change on the graph as long as it is part of `ax_2.lines`.  If you want to make it disappear, you should probably remove it from `ax_2.lines`.

Comment: But it shouldn't be a part of `ax_2.lines`, I changed its axes to `ax_1`. Unless I have completely misunderstood matplotlib, shouldn't both lines be shown in the same axes (the upper one) if they share the same axes?

Comment: The documentation indicates that the axis of the *line* is changed (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_axes); it does not say that the axis itself is modified.  This is what you observe.  I'm not sure what the typical use of `set_axis()` is, though, in these circumstances (line `f` remains contained in `ax_2.lines`, but indicates that its axis is `ax_1`, after your `set_axis()`: this seems contradictory…); so, I starred your question. :)

Comment: Yes I am a bit confused myself, not exactly intuitive behavior. Hopefully there is some matplotlib guru out there who can explain.